# I'm an Indonesian citizen. Do I need a visa for South Korea?

Tags: visas, south-korea, indonesian-citizens

I'm an Indonesian citizen holding an US visa. My itinerary is USA -> China -> South Korea -> China -> USA. All within 2 weeks. Do I need to apply for a South Korean visa?

Comment: The main thing is your itinerary is the wrong way around. You have to be coming to or from one of the nominated visa countries. You can't go to China first you should come to and from the US. I hope you got through. Did you have a problem coming from China?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you need a visa as an Indonesian passport holder. The only exemption, which applies to you, is where you have a re-entry visa and a travel plan including travel tickets to a country like the USA or Canada.

If you have a re-entry visa to the US, and you do not plan to stay in Korea longer than 30 days, you can enter [visa-free as a Transit tourist](http://www.hikorea.go.kr/pt/InfoDetailR_en.pt?categoryId=2&parentId=385&catSeq=401&showMenuId=375), bound for the USA as a holder of a re-entry visa to the USA.

Comment: I am just interested: How would holding a US Green card or visa have any bearing on his visa application to South Korea? As far as I know this would not be any use as a travel document?

Comment: According to this I might be able to enter without visa
http://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_client.cgi?ExpertMode=TIDFT/KR/VI/VS/ID40664&user=SKYWEB&subuser=SKYWEB1

http://sautsagala.wordpress.com/2007/11/28/indonesian-dont-need-visa-to-korea-if/

Comment: @Andrew South Korea seem to perceive US visa holders differently from people holding the same passport without a US visa.

Comment: @bingunginter Actually you are right. There is a difference depending on your onward journey, will fix above.